# Visualforce email template: Conditionally rendering table with 2 columns

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm trying to conditionally render a table with 2 columns per row. This is what I've tried:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10" border="0">
   <apex:variable var="i" value="{!1}" />
   <apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.Sample__r}" var="sample">
       <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(MOD(i,2)=1,true,false)}">
           <tr>
       </apex:outputText>
              <td><apex:OutputText value="{!sample.Id}"/></td>
       <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(MOD(i,2)=1,true,false)}">
           </tr>
       </apex:outputText>
       <apex:variable var="i" value="{!i+1}"/>
    </apex:repeat>
 </table>
```

I'm getting this error while trying to save the template:

```
Error: The element type "tr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</tr>".
```

I know it's complaining about the conditional code that does not include the end tag but how do I resolve this?

Comment: Why do you put <tr> tag within <apex:outputText> tag?

Comment: @OlehBerehovskyi My idea was to display `<tr>` and `</tr>` after every 2 `<td>`s. Not sure if my logic or the syntax is incorrect.

Comment: I recommend you to read about the <table> HTML element and its structure https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Comment: @OlehBerehovskyi I know the table structure. I'm just struggling to get this to work using the Visualforce syntax ie within the `<apex:repeat>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am getting your requirement correctly, you want to display the data in rows with two columns i.e. each `tr` should only have two `tds`

If that is the case, then you should make sure that you end all the tags properly. Also, when using `outputText`, you should set the `escape` attribute to `false`, so that it does not escape its values.

Your visualforce code should be something like below

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10" border="0">
    <tr>
        <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="i"/>
        <apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.Sample__r}"  var="sample">
            <apex:variable var="i" value="{!i +1}"/>
            <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(MOD(i,2)!=0, true, false)}" value="</tr><tr>" escape="false"></apex:outputText>
                <td width="50%">
                    <apex:OutputText value="{!sample.Id}"/>
                 </td>
                <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(MOD(i,2)!=0, true, false)}" value="<td/>" escape="false"></apex:outputText>
        </apex:repeat>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. However when I tried your code, I got this error: `Unknown property 'core.email.template.EmailTemplateComponentController.i`. So I used this instead: `<apex:variable value="{!0}" var="i"/>` and removed the `VALUE()` functions. Then it seemed to work. I'm still quite new to Salesforce. So I'm not sure what's going on. But anyway, your code has given me enough hints to proceed with my project.

Comment: Yup that was for the visualforce page with controller, updated with the corrections you mentioned so that it works for visualforce template.